# How to use php to strip text except specific elements

Tags: php, html, trim, strip

Instead of JavaScript, I am looking for the best way, in PHP, to strip out all other text or markup from within a `<a>` element, except `<spans>`. The parent `<a>` element does not provide a class name or id to target. For example:

I have this PHP:

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social-menu' ) ) { ?>
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'social-menu', 'fallback_cb' => '' ) );?>
<?php}?>
```

Which generates this html:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><span>icontext</span> some more text to hide1!</a></li>
    <li><a><span>icontext</span> some more text to hide1!</a></li>
    <li><a><span>icontext</span> some more text to hide1!</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like the end result to be:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a><span>icontext</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>icontext</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>icontext</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I understand the logic would be something like the following with proper stripping syntax:

```
if this = '<span>icontext</span>somemoretexttohide1!'
else if this = '<span>icontext</span> some more text to hide1!'
should just = '<span>icontext</span>'
```

Comment: Did u tried strip_tags()

Comment: I understand what it does and have been reading in PHP.net. `strip_tags("Hello <b><i>world!</i></b>","<b>")` I understand this would leave the `<b>` tags but remove the `<i>`. however I don't understand how to check to find an `<a>` then leave the `<spans>` and it's text, but remove all other internal text and characters outside the `span`. Especially since I'm not stripping a tag out. Just the content of a parent tag, but not so much so that it strips out the content of the span too. And then how to add all of that logic to the Wordpress array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the direction from @ben-shoval, one result ended up being this. Works great! If anyone has any further suggestions for performance improvement or a cleaner way, have at it and vote up.

```
<?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'social-menu' ) ) {

    // get the actual output of the html, but don't print it just yet.
    $menu = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'social-menu', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'echo' => false ) );

    // start removing all text except what's inside the spans.
    $start = 0;
        while ( strpos( $menu, "</span>", $start ) <> FALSE ) {
        $start = strpos( $menu, "</span>", $start )+7;
        $length = strpos( $menu, "</a>", $start ) - $start;
        $remove = substr( $menu, $start, $length );
        $menu = str_replace( $remove, "", $menu );
        ++$start;
    }

    // now that it's modified let this HTML print to screen.
    echo $menu;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a><span>icontext</span> some more text to hide1!</a></li>
      <li><a><span>icontext</span> some more text to hide1!</a></li>
      <li><a><span>icontext</span> some more text to hide1!</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  ";

$start = 0;
while ( strpos( $text, "</span>", $start ) <> FALSE ) {
  $start = strpos( $text, "</span>", $start );
  $length = strpos( $text, "</a>", $start ) - $start;
  $remove = substr( $text, $start, $length );
  $text = str_replace( $remove, "", $text );
  ++$start;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben... this is jump starting my brain. I realized I needed to first somehow get the wp_nav_menu into the $text. Then immediately generate it to search against it before it actually prints to the screen. `$text = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'social-menu', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'echo' => false ) );`